# How To Use Functions From Another Python File Through Kivy File

Tags: python, function, kivy, kivy-language

ok so my goal is to have a very clean slate as I like it when my code is organized, but that has also caused me too much trouble.

I have 3 *.py* files:

Main.py:

```
    # imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class DiceRollScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CoinFlipScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Calcu(Screen):
    pass


class TouchScreenTest(Screen):
    pass


class BinaryToTxt(Screen):
    pass


class TxtToBinary(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


BLD = Builder.load_file('KV_FILE.kv')


class QuickAppz(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(QuickAppz, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return BLD
    
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    QuickAppz().run()
```

function.py

```
def DiceRoll(start_num=0, end_num=6, modifier=0):
    import random
    DiceValue = random.randint(start_num, end_num)
    FinalValue = DiceValue + modifier
    int(FinalValue)
    return FinalValue


def CoinFlip():
    import random
    global Heads, Tails, CoinValue
    CoinValue = random.randint(1, 2)
    int(CoinValue)
    if CoinValue == 1:
        Heads = True
        Tails = False

    elif CoinValue == 2:
        Heads = False
        Tails = True
    else:
        print("ERROR")
```

KV_FILE.kv

```
# Pre-Styling


# Main Styling
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    DiceRollScreen:
    CoinFlipScreen:
    Calcu:
    TouchScreenTest:
    BinaryToTxt:
    TxtToBinary:


<MainScreen>:
    name: "Main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'Images\\Background 1.png'
        Button:
            text: "Calculator"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Calcu"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8
        Button:
            text: "Dice Simulator"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Dice"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8
        Button:
            text: "Coin Flip"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Coin"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8
        Button:
            text: "Binary To Text"
            on_release: app.root.current = "BTT"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8
        Button:
            text: "Text To Binary"
            on_release: app.root.current = "TTB"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8

        Button:
            text: "Touch Screen Test"
            on_release: app.root.current = "TST"
            background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8


<Calcu>:
    name: "Calcu"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"

<CoinFlipScreen>:
    name: "Coin"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
<DiceRollScreen>:
    name: "Dice"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        id: DiceRoller
<BinaryToTxt>:
    name: "BTT"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
<TxtToBinary>:
    name: "TTB"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
<TouchScreenTest>:
    name: "TST"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World"

    Button:
        text: "GO BACK"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
```

and one more extra.py files is there but there is no use for it yet

so my question is in function.py there is a function called CoinFlip and in KV_FILE.kv there is a button that I want to assign the CoinFLip Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import the `CoinFlip()` method in your `kv` file like this:

```
#: import CoinFlip function.CoinFlip
```

And then you can use it with a `Button`, like this:

```
    Button:
        text: "Coin Flip"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Coin"
            CoinFlip()
        background_color: .2,.2,.2,.8
```

Comment: Thank You So Much For This Answer, But I really Don't Get It

Comment: See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#import-package).

Comment: Thanks, so much dude, if i could I would up vote